# Client-side caching in Rich Internet Applications

Tags: ajax, gwt, caching, rich-internet-application

I'm starting to step into unfamiliar territory with regards to performance improvement and our RIA (Rich Internet Application) built with GWT. For those unfamiliar with GWT, essentially when deployed it's just pure JavaScript. We're interfacing with the server side using a REST-style XML web service via XMLHttpRequest.

Our XML is un-marshalled into JavaScript objects and used within the application to represent the data model behind the interface. When changes occur, the model is updated and marshalled back to XML and sent back to the server.

I've learned the number one rule of performance (in terms of user experience) is to make as few requests as possible. Obviously this brings up the possibility of caching. Caching is great for static data but things get tricky in a multi-user system where data on the server may be changing. Also, use of "Last-Modified" and "If-Modified-Since" requests don't quite do enough since we'd like to avoid unnecessary requests altogether.

I'm trying to figure out if caching data in the browser is even right for us before researching the approaches. I hope someone has tread this path before. I'm looking for similar approaches, lessons learned, things to avoid, etc.

I'm happy to provide more specific info if needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GWT, if performance matters that much to you, you get better performance by sending all the data you need in a single request, instead of querying multiple small data. I would recommend against client-side data caching as there are lots of issues like keeping the data in sync with the database.

Besides, you already have a good advantage with GWT over traditional html apps. Unless you are dealing with special data (eg: does not become stale too quickly - implies mostly-read queries) I found out that there is no special need for caching. You are better off doing a  service-layer caching, since most of the time should come of server-side processing.

If you can provide more details about the nature of the app, maybe some different conclusions can be taken.

Comment: I agree, batching data requests has provided a good speedup over multiple smaller requests. But the problem we're having a tricky time solving is determining exactly what is "all of the data you need". There has to be an upper bound.

Comment: There is no need to determine the upper bound if your service layer is defined with "small" enough services to be reused/re-called (for refreshing client screens, etc), but "big" enough to avoid "micro-management".